# Running Php Function in jQuery Append Html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I have a json and I want to append as html. There is also a foreach function just running appending couple of times. Everything is working fine like:

```
$('#drop1').append('<li><a href="#"><div class="row">'
        + '<div class="col-md-5">' + htmldata[i]['data'] + '</div>' // Working 
        + //more stuff..
);
```

However I want to append this kind of text into the above bit: (`$body->body` is also returned as json > `htmldata[i]['body']`)

```
<?php echo (strlen('$body->body') > 70) ? substr(($body->body),0,100)."..." : $body->body ?></div></a></li>');
```

---

Secondly, I also want to ask, if there is a way of using Laravel functions inside jQuery append such as, `{{{ $body->created_at->diffForHuman() }}}`
. (Created_at data is also returned as `htmldata[i]['created_at`]

Comment: You can't! These are 2 different environments. One is server-side and the other one is client-side. The bridge is the HTTP protocol. Use that bridge. How? Use Ajax.

Comment: The json data is called by ajax. Do you suggest me formatting the html document back in server, even before posting it to view? It's foreach function of jquery I am using

Comment: If you want to call a PHP function, yes. Since the route returns JSON you can manipulate the JSON by calling desired PHP functions. `{{{ }}}` just echos the datum. After manipulating the data you can leave the appending of them to JavaScript.